# Nested sizers in three panel Grid Layout in wxpython

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, wxgrid, boxsizer

I am building a GUI that consists of three panels and 2 grids(one grid in each panel). I am struggling with getting objects into their respective panels using the BoxSizer. It seems that the vertical boxsizer is only taking into account the upper and lower portions of the frame and not taking into account that the upper portion is a split into two panels. Therefore I am having a problem trying to organize widgets  vertically in the upper portion. When trying to add widgets to panelTwo, the vertical placement picks up from panelOne or vice versa. I would like to have a vertical boxsizer assigned to each panel if possible. Please excuse the sloppy code. I am only a few days into Python so take it easy on me! I am open to suggestions! Here is the section I am having trouble with:

```
    p1Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    p2Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    p3Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)`


    p3Sizer.Add(bottom_grid, 1, wx.EXPAND)#,pos=(200,200)

    p2Sizer.Add(p1Sizer)
    hbox1.Add(st1, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
    hbox1.Add(tc1, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
    hbox2.Add(st2, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
    hbox2.Add(tc2, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
    hbox3.Add(st3, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
    hbox3.Add(tc3, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
    p1Sizer.Add(hbox1,flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
    p1Sizer.Add(hbox2, flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
    p1Sizer.Add(hbox3, flag=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
```

If I include this line, panelTwo is formatted correctly. The only change is that the bottom box needs to be moved down.  See attachments.

`p2Sizer.Add(0,-120)`

[image: Line Added]

If I remove that line:

[image: Line removed]

But I feel that this is not the proper way to do this.
I am also trying to find a way to create two separate grids with different amount of rows. i.e

`self.CreateGrid(100, 27)`

and...

'self.CreateGrid(5, 27)'

`import wx
 import wx.grid as gridlib
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np`

`class MyGrid(gridlib.Grid):
    def __init__(self, parent):`

```
    """Constructor"""
    gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, parent)

    self.CreateGrid(100, 27)
```

`class MasterPanel(wx.Panel):`

```
def __init__(self, parent, color):
    """Constructor"""
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
    self.SetBackgroundColour(color)`
```

`class MainPanel(wx.Panel):`

```
def __init__(self, parent):`

    """Constructor"""
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)`

    topSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
    vSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(topSplitter)
    font = wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT)

    font.SetPointSize(50)

    panelOne = MasterPanel(vSplitter, "light grey")
    panelTwo = MasterPanel(vSplitter, "white")
    panelThree = MasterPanel(topSplitter,"white")

    vSplitter.SplitVertically(panelOne, panelTwo)
    vSplitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(300) # 300

    vSplitter.SetSashGravity(.5)


    topSplitter.SplitHorizontally(vSplitter, panelThree)
    topSplitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(200) #200
    topSplitter.SetSashGravity(1)
    #topSplitter.SetSashGravity(1)
```

`# Assign grid to BOTTOM PANEL
        bottom_grid = MyGrid(panelThree)
        top_grid= MyGrid(panelTwo)`

```
    st1 = wx.StaticText(panelOne, -1,"Name")
    st1.SetFont(font)
    st2 = wx.StaticText(panelOne, -1,"Date:")    
    st2.SetFont(font)
    st3 = wx.StaticText(panelOne, -1,"Input #:")
    st3.SetFont(font)
    st4 = wx.StaticText(panelTwo, -1,"From Source:")
    st4.SetFont(font)
    st5 = wx.StaticText(panelTwo, -1,"Lookup:")
    st5.SetFont(font)
    st6 = wx.StaticText(panelTwo, -1,"Lookup Value:")
    st6.SetFont(font)

    tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(panelOne,size=(150,25), value="-enter name-")
    tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(panelOne,size=(150,25), value="-enter date-")
    tc3 = wx.TextCtrl(panelOne, value="-input item #'")
    tc4 = wx.TextCtrl(panelTwo, value="-Search-")

    options= ['A','B','C']

    combo1 = wx.ComboBox(panelTwo,size=(150,25),value="-Choose Source-",choices=options, 
    style=wx.LB_SINGLE)
    combo2 = wx.ComboBox(panelTwo,size=(150,25),value="-Choose Lookup Type-",choices=options, 
    style=wx.LB_SINGLE)

    hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    hbox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    hbox4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    hbox5 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    hbox6 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    p1Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    p2Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    p3Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)


    p3Sizer.Add(bottom_grid, 1, wx.EXPAND)#,pos=(200,200)

    p2Sizer.Add(p1Sizer)
    hbox1.Add(st1, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
    hbox1.Add(tc1, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
    hbox2.Add(st2, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
    hbox2.Add(tc2, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
    hbox3.Add(st3, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
    hbox3.Add(tc3, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
    p1Sizer.Add(hbox1,flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
    p1Sizer.Add(hbox2, flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
    p1Sizer.Add(hbox3, flag=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)


    #p2Sizer.Add(0,-120)

    hbox4.Add(st4, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
    hbox4.Add(combo1, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
    hbox5.Add(st5, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
    hbox5.Add(combo2, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
    hbox6.Add(st6, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
    hbox6.Add(tc4, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
    p2Sizer.Add(hbox4)
    p2Sizer.Add(hbox5)
    p2Sizer.Add(hbox6)




    #p1Sizer.Add(p1, 2, wx.EXPAND)#,pos=(200,200)
    p2Sizer.Add(top_grid, 1, wx.EXPAND)#,pos=(200,200)


    panelThree.SetSizer(p3Sizer)
    panelTwo.SetSizer(p2Sizer)
    #panelOne.SetSizer(p1Sizer)

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    #sizer.Add(top_grid)
    sizer.Add(topSplitter, -1, wx.EXPAND)

    #panelTwo.SetSizer(sizer)
    self.SetSizer(sizer)
```

`class MainFrame(wx.Frame):`

```
def __init__(self):
    """Constructor"""
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Hell Yeah",
                      size=(1600,700))
    panel = MainPanel(self)
    self.Show()   `
```

`if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()'`

Comment: This question would benefit from a picture/diagram of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Edited and added pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've "interpreted" your image, dumping the split windows, which add nothing but complication. I also dumped the font size.
Feel free to use the code below as a starting point and re-instate them if they are essential.

**Update:** after OP amended the question's image

It's just a matter of dividing the layout into boxes. In this case and the addition of the extra grid in the question image, it's just some more virtual boxes that are required. (I choose to split p2 into p21 and p22, then place them into p2. The only reason this is necessary to to correctly align the 3 `selection` widgets and their text)
I limit the size of the top grid with `top_grid.SetMaxSize((-1,80))`

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib

class MyGrid(gridlib.Grid):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, parent)

        self.CreateGrid(100, 27)

class MasterPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, color):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(color)

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        font = wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT)

        panelOne = MasterPanel(self, "light grey")
        panelTwo = MasterPanel(self, "white")
        panelThree = MasterPanel(self,"white")

    # Assign grid to BOTTOM PANEL
        bottom_grid = MyGrid(panelThree)
        top_grid = MyGrid(panelTwo)
        top_grid.SetMaxSize((-1,80))

        st1 = wx.StaticText(panelOne, -1,"Name")
        st1.SetFont(font)
        st2 = wx.StaticText(panelOne, -1,"Date:")
        st2.SetFont(font)
        st3 = wx.StaticText(panelOne, -1,"Input #:")
        st3.SetFont(font)
        st4 = wx.StaticText(panelTwo, -1,"From Source:")
        st4.SetFont(font)
        st5 = wx.StaticText(panelTwo, -1,"Lookup:")
        st5.SetFont(font)
        st6 = wx.StaticText(panelTwo, -1,"Lookup Value:")
        st6.SetFont(font)

        tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(panelOne, value="-enter name-")
        tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(panelOne, value="-enter date-")
        tc3 = wx.TextCtrl(panelOne, value="-input item #'")
        tc4 = wx.TextCtrl(panelTwo, value="-Search-")

        options= ['Option 1','Option 2','Option 3']

        combo1 = wx.ComboBox(panelTwo,value="-Choose Source-",choices=options,
        style=wx.LB_SINGLE)
        combo2 = wx.ComboBox(panelTwo,value="-Choose Lookup Type-",choices=options,
        style=wx.LB_SINGLE)

        hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox5 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox6 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox7 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        p1Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        p2Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        p21Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        p22Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        p3Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        p4Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        p3Sizer.Add(bottom_grid, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        hbox1.Add(st1, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        hbox1.Add(tc1, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        hbox2.Add(st2, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        hbox2.Add(tc2, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        hbox3.Add(st3, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        hbox3.Add(tc3, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        p1Sizer.Add(hbox1, flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
        p1Sizer.Add(hbox2, flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
        p1Sizer.Add(hbox3, flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)

        hbox4.Add(st4, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        hbox4.Add(combo1, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        hbox5.Add(st5, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        hbox5.Add(combo2, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        hbox6.Add(st6, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        hbox6.Add(tc4, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        hbox7.Add(top_grid, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        p21Sizer.Add(hbox4, flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
        p21Sizer.Add(hbox5, flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
        p21Sizer.Add(hbox6, flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
        p22Sizer.Add(hbox7)

        p2Sizer.Add(p21Sizer)
        p2Sizer.Add(p22Sizer)

        panelThree.SetSizer(p3Sizer)
        panelTwo.SetSizer(p2Sizer)
        panelOne.SetSizer(p1Sizer)

        mainsizer_top = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        mainsizer_bottom = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        mainsizer_top.Add(panelOne, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        mainsizer_top.Add(panelTwo, 0,)
        mainsizer_bottom.Add(panelThree, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        mainsizer.Add(mainsizer_top, 0,)
        mainsizer.Add(mainsizer_bottom, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(mainsizer)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Hell Yeah",
                          size=(1600,700))
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: I apologize, my second image didn't uploaded. Should be updated. I have three panels because the bottom and top right contain a grid. The bottom panel is for data entry/retrieval and the top right corner is to lookup any missing information that needs to be inputted. That is the reason for the splitterwindow. However, I appreciate the edit!

Comment: That's it! However, I've lost the ability to resize each panel. I will have to compare to my current code to see how I can implement it.

Comment: Splitterwindows only allow adjustments in 1 direction. See `Advanced User Interface` for a more comprehensive approach. https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.aui.1moduleindex.html